# Git submodules with config files

Tags: git, git-submodules

If I want to submodule a Git repository:

https://github.com/shadowhand/paypal

...that has a config file:

https://github.com/shadowhand/paypal/blob/master/config/paypal.php

...how do I contribute to the project without committing my version of the config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you commit, don't add that file:

```
git add classes/paypal.php
...
# don't add config/paypal.php
git commit
```

Before committing, check with `git status` that you haven't staged any modifications to the config - if you accidentally have, use `git reset HEAD config/paypal.php` to unstage them.

(And for what it's worth, this doesn't really have anything to do with the fact that you're using this repository as a submodule.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer...just learning Git, really appreciate it.  How do I get updates from the repository without overwriting my local config file?

Comment: @tim: Try running `git pull`. If there haven't been modifications in the remote version of the config file, git will trivially leave your modifications in place. If there have been changes, it'll refuse to try to merge. At that point, you can `git stash` to stash away your local changes, `git pull`, then `git stash pop` to reapply your changes - though there may be merge conflicts, since you've probably edited the same things they have. (This is all assuming you properly don't commit your changes.)

Comment: P.S. It'd really be better if the project provided `config-default.php`, and ignored `config.php`, so that you could drop in your own config without this mess.

Comment: Great....thanks for the clarification.  Presumably, if I'm going to contribute to the project, I could implement the config-default.php strategy.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered how Kohana suggest you manage your local config files.

From the Database module:
http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/database/config

> The default config file is located in
>   MODPATH/database/config/database.php.
>   You should copy this file to
>   APPPATH/config/database.php and make
>   changes there, in keeping with the
>   [cascading filesystem](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/files).

Hope that helps.